# How to use or add a shared library (.so) into a C++ project in CLion and use method contained on .so file

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, clion, .so

I have a c++ method on .so lib that receive a number and return "hello world". Then how can i import it on other c++ project on cMakeList and call on main.cpp. but i have a doubt how can i inform a compiler that .hpp methods declarated was implemented on .so lib.
tried to include .so lib on cMakeList and created .h file that declared a function that receive a number and return a string. I having this issue undefined reference to

Comment: "I having this issue undefined reference to" - That is, something wrong with your `.so` file or with the header file. You need to add your **code** into the question post. Otherwise we simply cannot help you.

Comment: Could also be something wrong with your CMakeLists.txt however since we can't see it we can't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a library with CMake, then you install it somewhere or make it available on an artifact repository / server, then you can use it with CMake by providing its location and using `find_package` in the consuming project.